# Read values from SQL Server database using vba

Tags: sql-server, vba

i am using vba studio and would like to read some values from a sql database.

Here is my code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class log
    Dim usuariovb As String
    Dim passwordvb As String

    Private Sub exe_log_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles exe_log.Click
        usuariovb = txt_user.Text
        passwordvb = txt_pw.Text

        Dim sConnectionString As String = "Server=MXD071352\SQLEXPRESS; Database=CALLC; User Id=sa;Password=Kernmic1"
        Using objConn As New SqlConnection(sConnectionString)
            Dim comando As New SqlCommand("SELECT Contraseña from Usuarios WHERE Usuario = '" & usuariovb & "';", objConn)
            objConn.Open()
            Dim lector As SqlDataReader = comando.ExecuteReader()
            Try
                While lector.Read()
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", lector(0), lector(2)))
                End While
            Finally
                lector.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Could you please help me, since I am not getting results

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: what is vba studio?

Comment: I get index out of rate on this line: Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", lector(0), lector(2)))

Comment: This is not VBA. It looks to be VB.Net. Please tag appropriately. As mentioned in [vba] tag: *VBA is not equivalent to VB.Net, or VBS. If you're working in Visual Studio use [vb.net]*

Comment: You are reading one single column (`Contraseña`) and yet you're accessing `lector(2)`. That's not going to fly.

Comment: I tried with just one column but still not working